# PayPal Error: We’re sorry things don’t appear to be working at the moment. please try again later

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I manage some WordPress/WooCommerce online shops which have been running problem free for a few years.  Recently, we have noticed that our transactions via Paypal have not been working.

I tried to process an order myself using PayPal and got the following error:

> We’re sorry things don’t appear to be working at the moment. please
>   try again later paypal

WooCommerce have suggested it's not a problem with their software but most likely a problem with the specific PayPal account. As usual, PayPal support is saying "there's no problem with PayPal"

Without pulling apart the WooCommerce code, I'm not sure where to go next...

Comment: I recently got this error and followed the [PayPal article](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/ts2067) however it turned out that the PayPal account was temporarily limited since the website had violated the PayPal's Acceptable Use Policy. Checkout your account's message center.

Answer (score 7):

Issue : Customers are receiving error: Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.

This error typically occurs for two reasons:

1.) You have entered your PayPal email address or PayPal Identity Token incorrectly. Please confirm your PayPal email address and PayPal Identity Token are entered correctly within Downloads => Settings => Payment Gateways => PayPal Standard

> Or

2.) Your customers may also see this if Encrypted Website Payments set to ON. Setting it to OFF will resolve the issue. This setting can be adjusted from within your PayPal account by navigating to Profile => Profile and Settings => Selling Preferences => (Website Payment Preferences/Website Preferences) and selecting OFF under Encrypted Website Payments

[image]

[Powered by :-)](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/2030-paypal-error-things-dont-appear-to-be-working-at-the-moment)

Answer (score 0):

Check paypal setting at Admin panel and Paypal account both
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/

Answer (score 0):

Your Instant Payment Notification (IPN) URL must match your store's URL

Under **Profile & Settings > SElling Tools > Instant payment notifications**
Click update, then add your store's URL

You also need to check **API access > NVP/SOAP API integration (Classic)** 
In the section **Credential Signature** , find these values and submit it to your Woocommerce payment settings

1. API Username
2. API Password
3. Signature

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything then came across a post and fixed the issue. It had something to do with Memcached. I uninstalled it and now my customers are able to pay with debit and credit card. https://simonward.net/paypal-checkout-error-when-paying-with-credit-or-debit-card/

Answer (score 0):

There's another possibility aside from not accepting encrypted website payments: for some reason the transaction IDs are being perceived as duplicates even though they are new transactions.

Go to your account settings in paypal and check your payment preferences. Disable the settings that rejects payments with duplicate transaction IDs and make a test transaction. You should now be able to receive payments while you spend time figuring out what went wrong.

I'm attaching the error message I got when I submitted the payment request below for your reference.

```
{ack: "contingency", contingency: "DUPLICATE_INVOICE_ID", errorData: {},…}
ack: "contingency"
contingency: "DUPLICATE_INVOICE_ID"
errorData: {}
meta: ...
calc: ...
rlog: ...
server: ...
```

[image: payment preferences]

[image: block payments]