# PayPal _xclick-subscriptions not working with sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I try implement and test PayPal payment with subscriptions with sandbox but every time give "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

I already off Encrypted website payments as per below reference:
[PayPal Error: We’re sorry things don’t appear to be working at the moment. please try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297743/paypal-error-we-re-sorry-things-don-t-appear-to-be-working-at-the-moment-pleas)

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/websc?business=abidhussainmerchan@xxx.com&cmd=_xclick-subscriptions&no_shipping=1&amount=1.0&p3=1.0&t3=Y&src=1&custom=23@@@153&no_note=1&item_name=My+item+subscription&currency_code=USD&rm=2&address_override=1&first_name=rose&last_name=roja&address1=NY&address2=NY&city=New York&state=NY&zip=10001&country=US&return=http://new.xxxx.localhost/index.php?path=thankyou&cancel=http://new.xxx.localhost/index.php?path=signup&notify_url=http://new.xxx.localhost/index.php?path=ipn
```

This is my Form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abidhussainmerchan@xxx.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Prod 1 Subscription">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="26@@@156">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

    <!-- Enable override of buyers's address stored with PayPal . -->
    <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
    <!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Rose">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Roja">
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="aa">
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="cc">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="New York">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="10001">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://new.xxx.localhost/index.php?path=thankyou">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel" value="http://new.xxx.localhost/index.php?path=signup">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://new.xxx.localhost/index.php?path=ipn">
    <input type="image" name="submit" id="paypal-btn" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

This is because of incorrect shipping address being passed. Replace the below sample shipping parameters

```
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Philadelphia">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19108">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
```